# Hide all divs of a class, show only those with additional class

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of DIVS (products on a storepage) width the class "chairdiv".
I'd like to be able to filter the DIVS that have an additional class, here's an example:

```
<div class="chairdiv sold"></div>
<div class="chairdiv forsale"></div>
<div class="chairdiv forsale"></div>
<div class="chairdiv forsale"></div>
<div class="chairdiv sold"></div>
<div class="chairdiv forsale"></div>
```

By default the page would show all these divs, can I use javascript to hide all "chairdiv" divs except those with "sold" or "forsale" as an additional class?

I'm HTML/CSS proficient but I know very little javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thoughts:

```
$('.chairdiv').not('.sold, .forsale').hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jE5zn/).

**Edited** in response to question from the OP:

> can you tell me how to activate this function with HTML? For example, to show only `<div class="chairdiv sold"></div>`, what could i put here: `<a href="(what here)">show sold chairs</a>`

For this:

```
<a href="#" id="showChairsAndSold">Show chairs and sold</a>

$('#showChairsAndSold').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents any default action
        $('.chairdiv').not('.sold, .forsale').hide();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jE5zn/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Comment: Beat me to it, though mine included comments breaking it down. ;p

Comment: I tend to post the answer, as I imagine it would work (with the 'albeit untested' comment), then go test it and make sure, post a link to the demo and *then* post the references and any other comments I feel might be useful. In this case it took longer to work through the demo because *none of the `div`s were hiding...* and it took me a second to realise that none of them lacked the second class. D'oh..! =/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, can you tell me how to activate this function with HTML? For example, to show only <div class="chairdiv sold"></div>, what could i put here: <a href="(what here)">show sold chairs</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".chairdiv").filter('.sold, .forsale');
```

This takes all elements with "chardiv" class, then returns only those with classes "sold" or "forsale".

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically asked how to hide divs (in case you have other tags that may have the `chairdiv` class that you **don't** want to hide) (which I know sounds funny since "div" is in the class name, but you did ask specifically for divs):

```
$("div.chairdiv").not(".sold, .forsale").hide();
```